# Using switch case to validate form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, switch-statement

I am creating a form validation with 2 conditions to validate. Is this a good way to use switch case with if else statement? Or is this something that is frown upon? If so, what would a better way to approach this without using external library, thank you.

Code:

```
const validate = ( name, value) => {
   switch (name) {
   case "user_name":
if (!value) {
 setErrors({ ...errors, user_name: "Please, submit required data" });
 } else if (!new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/).test(value)) {
 setErrors({
...errors,
 user_name: "Please, provide the data of indicated type(no special characters)",
});
 } else {
let newObj = omit(errors, "user_name");
 setErrors({ ...newObj });
 }
 break;
.....
```

Comment: It will make it tougher to read, a small improvement would be to extract your `setErrors` out to another function like `setUserNameErrors()`. This would at least make it a bit more readable and not have switch and the if-else mixed in the same block.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very readable so I wouldn't say it's the best way, but it's definitely not the worst. You could try something like this.

```
const validate = (name, value) => {
  if (!value) {
    setErrors({ ...errors, [name]: "Please, submit required data" })
    return
  }
  
  switch (name) {
    case "user_name": {
      if (!new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/).test(value)) {
        setErrors({
          ...errors,
          user_name: "Please, provide the data of indicated type(no special characters)"
        })
        return
      }
    }
  }
  
  const newObj = omit(errors, name)
  setErrors({ ...newObj })
}
```